# Drag and Drop Godot 4: Disappears when dropped outside allowed area

Tags: godot, godot-4

I'm trying to make a simple drag and drop function, and it works when dragging from one area to another, but if I accidentally drop the sprite outside the allowed areas, it just disappears. I've been trying to have it set up so that the sprite, if dropped outside the area, returns to its last known location. Here is the code I have, although it does not work as the sprite still disappears:

```
extends TextureRect

var original_position : Vector2

func _get_drag_data(at_position):
    original_position = position
    
    var preview_texture = TextureRect.new()
    preview_texture.texture = texture
    preview_texture.expand_mode = 1
    preview_texture.size = Vector2(90,90)
    
    var preview = Control.new()
    preview.add_child(preview_texture)
    
    set_drag_preview(preview)
    
    
    texture = null
    return preview_texture.texture
    
func _can_drop_data(at_position, data):
    return data is Texture2D
    
func _drop_data(at_position, data):
    if _can_drop_data(at_position, data):
        texture = data
    else:
        texture = data
        position = original_position
```

My node tree looks like:

- Node2D

  - TextureRect

    - Panel
  - TextureRect

    - Panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Godot calls `_drop_data`, it will call `_can_drop_data`. Furthermore, if `_can_drop_data` returned `false`, Godot will not call `_drop_data`.

So in this code:

```
func _can_drop_data(at_position, data):
    return data is Texture2D
    
func _drop_data(at_position, data):
    if _can_drop_data(at_position, data):
        texture = data
    else:
        texture = data
        position = original_position
```

Calling `_can_drop_data` from `_drop_data` is redundant, and the execution flow will never enter the `else` statement.

---

The above, of course, is only called when attempting to drop on the `TextureRect` with the shown script. So that code won't handle dropping outside.

Try checking for `NOTIFICATION_DRAG_END` in `_notification`, where you can check if drag failed:

```
func _notification(what:int) -> void:
    if what == NOTIFICATION_DRAG_END and not is_drag_successful():
        print("Drag Failed")
```

Comment: How would I be able to have it reappear in its original location though? This does say that the drag is not successful, but it does not provide any insight on how to get it to go back to its original position. I tried incorporating the `is_drag_successful()` function into the `_drop_data()` function but that did not change anything.

Comment: @lzzard Is there any reason you can't put the code for that inside `_notification`?